# Negative values in Sankey diagram visualizing losses

Tags: pandas, plotly, visualization, sankey-diagram

```
US_TOTAL_REVENUE = 50
INTERNATIONAL_TOTAL_REVENUE = 50
REVENUE = 100
GROSS_PROFIT = 10
COST_OF_REVENUE = 110
```

We have a business that operates on a loss. Their `COST_OF_REVENUE` (110) is higher than their `REVENUE` (100) resulting in a `GROSS_PROFIT / LOSS` of 10.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

source = [0, 1, 2, 2,]
target = [2, 2, 3, 4,]
value = [US_TOTAL_REVENUE, INTERNATIONAL_TOTAL_REVENUE, GROSS_PROFIT, COST_OF_REVENUE]
label = [f'US_TOTAL_REVENUE {value[0]}', f'INTERNATIONAL_TOTAL_REVENUE {value[1]}', f'REVENUE {REVENUE}',
         f'GROSS_PROFIT {value[2]}',f'COST_OF_REVENUE {value[3]}']
d = {'source': source, 'target': target, 'value':value}#, 'label':label}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
nodes = np.unique(df[["source", "target"]], axis=None)
nodes = pd.Series(index=nodes, data=range(len(nodes)))

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Sankey(
        arrangement="snap",
        node={"label": label, "pad" : 20},
        link={"source": source, "target": target, "value": value},
    )
)
fig.show()
```

If I use a negative value for `GROSS_PROFIT` no link will be shown. If I use a positive value it will result in the following graphic.

[image: Wrong Sankey Plot]

I do not want to change the `COST_OF_REVENUE` value because it will be split up into multiple other links and nodes (not shoen in the graphic), so the wrong value would propagate into other layers.

Is there an algorithm or a visualization technique for negative values in sankey diagrams?